# Fixed width. Automatic text resize?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

I'm currently working in personalised product design, I get a document with the customers name or date ect and I insert the information into the illustrator file and save it out as a pdf.

I've managed to find ways and create actions in all my other areas of work to speed everything up.

The thing that takes me the longest is getting a super long or really short name to personalise a product with.

I was wondering if you knew of a way where I could just paste in someones name, then the text resizes itself to fit. so like creating a fixed width/height for a design, then whatever name i paste in, it goes to that width?

thanks

Comment: It be nice if you at least accepted the answer @Craig

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Adobe scripting, this very common issue can be solved via script. Please view [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695473/scale-text-to-fit-in-a-text-box-in-illustrator-using-scriptsjavascript/46718621#46718621) to find the similar question.

The link I provide is to my LinkedIn article which deals with this script and its usage: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adobe-illustrator-variable-data-dealing-overset-text-vasily-hall/

If you are doing much personalization, you may be interested in the variable data capabilities of Adobe Illustrator. If so, please add [me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vasily-hall-91216618/) on LinkedIn to view all of my various variable data articles. Fair warning to all visitors: **for nerds ONLY!**